# how to counter last value with length+1?

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have form like this :

```
<div id='add_field' class='locbutton'><a href='#' title='Add'>Add</a></div>
<div id='remove_field' class='locbutton2'><a href='#' title='Delete'>Delete</a></div>
<div id='idisikpi'>
<div id='idheadisi1' class='headisi'>
<div class='performancedetail'><input type='text' name='idperformancedetail[1][]' 
value='2' id='idperformancedetail[1][]'></div>
<div class='performancedetail'><input type='text' name='idperformancedetail[2][]' 
value='9' id='idperformancedetail[2][]'></div>
</div>
 </div>
```

This is the jquery script :

```
function CreateInput()
{

    var $headisi = $("<div>"),
    $idperformancedetail=$("<div>");

  var headisi_count = $("div.headisi").length+1;
  var idperformancedetail_count = 
  $("[id^='idperformancedetail']").last().val().length+1;

  $headisi.addClass("headisi");
  $idperformancedetail.addClass("performancedetail");

  var $input_idperformancedetail = $("<input>")

  $input_idperformancedetail
    .attr("name", "idperformancedetail["+headisi_count+"][]")
    .attr("type", "text")
    .attr("id", "idperformancedetail["+headisi_count+"][]")
    .attr("value", idperformancedetail_count);
  $idperformancedetail.append($input_idperformancedetail);

    $headisi.append($idperformancedetail);

  return $headisi;
}



$("#add_field a").click(function(e)
{
$("#idisikpi").append(CreateInput());

e.preventDefault();
});

$("#remove_field a").click(function(e){
$("#idisikpi div.headisi:last-child").remove();
CalculateTotal();

e.preventDefault();
});
```

I want the next input is counter from last value of idperformancedetail, i want value on the next input like 10,11,12,...What can i do to get counter value on the next input ? Please Help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse `$("[id^='idperformancedetail']").last().val()` as an integer ([`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)), otherwise you'll get a concatenated  string. Also you don't want to use `.length`, but [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
var idperformancedetail_count = parseInt($("[id^='idperformancedetail']").last().val()) + 1;
```

[JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/5gyHZ/). Note that `val()` will only work since you set the `value` attribute in the `div` yourself. This will completely ignore your `input`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

Get the count of existing checkboxes like so:

```
var existingInputCount = $('input[name^=idperformancedetail]').length;
```

Then use `existingInputCount` accordingly.